# Auto refresh for a jTextField from JDBC when login

Tags: java, string, jdbc, jtextfield, settext

I'm making an APP for customer manager, but I'm not being able to retrieve the DB sets and string them onto jTextField. Basically I made a Login screen, and once it's logged I want to make a mini panel on button showing the name of the seller.

I've created a Boolean on the DB, so I'm trying to make the code read the table and search the one which is enabled. Made it in a way where only one of the data are Boolean true, so I know that is not the problem.

Here is the Main Window Part:

```
private void vendorNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    DBConn.connect();
    try {
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/vitrini", "developer", "admin");
       String sql = "SELECT ? FROM DEVELOPER.VENDOR WHERE logged = ?";
       PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       ps.setString(1, "name");
       ps.setBoolean(2, true);
       ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next()) {
           String user = rs.getString("name");
           vendorName.setText(user);
           vendorName.repaint();
           evt.getModifiers();
       }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}
```

And this is the Login Screen that turns the Boolean on:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    SessionManager.nullSession();
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/vitrini", "developer", "admin");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DEVELOPER.VENDOR WHERE name='"+typedUser.getText()+"' AND PASSWORD='"+typedPass.getText()+"'");
        String user = typedUser.getText();
        String pass = typedPass.getText();
        if(user == "") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O campo de Usuário não pode ficar em branco.");
        } else if(pass == "") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O campo de Senha não pode ficar em branco.");
        } else if(rs.next()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login realizado com sucesso.");
                String update = "UPDATE DEVELOPER.VENDOR SET logged = ? WHERE name = ?";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(update);
                ps.setBoolean(1, true);
                ps.setString(2, typedUser.getText());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                MainFrameGUI gui = new MainFrameGUI();
                gui.setVisible(true);
                
                this.dispose();
        }
        else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário ou senha incorretos.");
        }
    }
    catch(HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

The jTextField is NOT EDITABLE, but keeps empty when it's done.
Hope someone can help me out with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `user == ""` is not how you compare `String` in Java, you should be using `String#equals` or in your case you could just as easily use `user.trim().isEmpty()` for the same effect

Comment: So, which part of you code is call `vendorNameActionPerformed`?

Comment: I'd also suggest that it would be easier to pass information you already have to the `MainFrameGUI` when you create it

Comment: vendorNameActionPerformed is the statement from the MainWindowGUI, vendorName is the jTextField itself, about the ="" part, thanks alot, it got 100%

Comment: vendorName is the part that i'm wrecking my brian off, cause there is no call for it, it is supposed to auto update or something, it will retreive from DB the unique data that has the boolean true, so it has to string into the vendorName
Basically is >> Login will set the boolean true for the current user, then i want this vendorName textfield to auto update with the name of THAT user. i suppose the sql call method is correct.

Comment: If no one is calling the `vendorNameActionPerformed` method, then nothing will get updated. Personally, I look towards passing the information you already have in the `jButton1ActionPerformed` to the constructor of `MainFrameGUI` or provide a setter to pass that information, rather then hitting the database again